# libGDX html compile error tools.jar not found

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to run the sample project from libGDX but i cant seem to get the html one working, the android and the desktop ones are working fine. When i try to compile the project i get this error:

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

```
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                                                     
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE     
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE      
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE      
:html:compileJava FAILED    

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':html:compileJava'.
Could not find tools.jar
```

My java path should be good since it is able to compile the android and desktop ones.